# Javascript find Array elements within Array of Objects values without a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is it possible to look for `arr` elements in `arrofobjs` without a for loop? Since `'Buddy'` is in both `arr` and `arrofobjs`, i'd expect `found` to return `true`

```
var arrofobjs = [ { type: 'Dog', name: 'Buddy', color: 'White' },
  { type: 'Cat', name: 'Misty', color: 'Black' },
  { type: 'Dog', name: 'Max', color: 'Black' }, ]
var arr = [ 'Buddy', 'Oscar' ]
var found = Object.values(arrofobjs).some(r=> arr.includes(r)) //returns false, but would return true if arrofobj was an object
```

Comment: I think you want `arr.includes(r.name)` << you need to look for the `name` attribute

Comment: I reckon that you should explicitly say *"without a for loop"*, or maybe defining the kind of loop you want to avoid (`while`, `forEach` etc), because all answers here (`some`, `includes`, `find` etc...) do use loops internally. After all, if you stop to think, from the machine viewpoint this is impossible to do without looping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to access the `name` *property*.

```js
var arrofobjs = [ { type: 'Dog', name: 'Buddy', color: 'White' },
  { type: 'Cat', name: 'Misty', color: 'Black' },
  { type: 'Dog', name: 'Max', color: 'Black' }, ]
var arr = [ 'Buddy', 'Oscar' ]
var found = Object.values(arrofobjs).some(r => arr.includes(r.name))
console.log(found);
```

Since `arrofobjs` is an array, you can directly apply the `some` method by using *destructing*.

```js
var arrofobjs = [ { type: 'Dog', name: 'Buddy', color: 'White' },
{ type: 'Cat', name: 'Misty', color: 'Black' },
{ type: 'Dog', name: 'Max', color: 'Black' }, ]
var arr = [ 'Buddy', 'Oscar' ]
var found = arrofobjs.some(({name}) => arr.includes(name))
console.log(found);
```

Comment: As `arrofobjs` is an array, no need to use `Object.values()`

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there. As `arrofobjs` is an array, you can directly iterate over it.

```js
var arrofobjs = [ { type: 'Dog', name: 'Buddy', color: 'White' },{ type: 'Cat', name: 'Misty', color: 'Black' },{ type: 'Dog', name: 'Max', color: 'Black' }];
var arr = [ 'Buddy', 'Oscar' ];
var found = arrofobjs.some(({name})=> arr.includes(name));
console.log(found);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method of array to find the record in array.

**DEMO**

```js
var arrofobjs = [ { type: 'Dog', name: 'Buddy', color: 'White' },
  { type: 'Cat', name: 'Misty', color: 'Black' },
  { type: 'Dog', name: 'Max', color: 'Black' }],
  arr = ['Buddy', 'Oscar'];
  
arr.forEach(v=>console.log(arrofobjs.find(({name})=>name==v)||`${v} Not fond`));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
```